# Dokuwiki and Javascript

Tags: javascript, dokuwiki

Recently I saw this post about a "Go Top" button of this user that uses Jquery and want it converted to Mootools. I think this would be a nice feature for the free templates I'm writting to contribute to the project. But unfortunately I this type of javascript is not working. I know jquery, I tried the code in jquery and didn't work. Then I took this peace of code converted to mootools and is not working to... The forums aren't a big help because there's no answer...

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
   $('gototop').setStyle('display','none');
   ((window.getScrollSize().y + 300 )> window.getSize().y) ? $('gototop').fade(1) : $('gototop').fade(0)  
});
```

Does anyone know which type of language dokuwiki uses to javascript??? Can anyone with more experience with the platform show me how to write this so I can use with dokuwiki?
Like the original poster I want the button to by hidden and show only if the user scrolls the window 300px...if not the button should be hidden. Then if the user doesn't have javascript activated the button should be always on...

Dokuwiki has a plugin to use jquery but I prefer use his native language...

Thanks,
Ana

Answer (score 0):

Dokuwiki uses jQuery. but you have to use 'jQuery' and not the default '$'
Also DokuWiki has moved away from the old js framework and its now using jquery only for everything (the move is till going on). you can have a look at https://github.com/piyushmishra/dokuwiki-extension-manager/blob/master/script.js for better idea of how to go about it. and also at http://www.dokuwiki.org/devel:javascript